# How would you replace this rewrite rule with a redirect?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

[This](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html) Apache reference page and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) wiki clearly states that to achieve simple http to https redirects, `mod_alias` should be used instead of the more expensive `mod_rewrite`.

I have an Apache virtualhost which uses a wildcard to match multiple subdomains. *I need all these subdomains redirected to their corresponding https counterparts*. Currently, I am using the following (with mod_rewrite):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName lvh.me
    ServerAlias *.lvh.me

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried the following, **but it did not work**.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName lvh.me
    ServerAlias *.lvh.me

    Redirect temp / https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
</VirtualHost>
```

The apache variable `HTTP_HOST` doesn't seem to be recognized in redirect directives.

So, is there any other way to use mod_alias to achieve the above effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.  `Redirect` is able to handle simple redirections, where you're sending the client to a single, specific name, but does not have the ability to do complex substitutions (setting aside the fact that `%{HTTP_HOST}` is `mod_rewrite`-specific).

Just stick with `mod_rewrite`.  `mod_alias` isn't capable of doing what you need.

Comment: I suspected that `HTTP_HOST` is `mod-rewrite` specific. But I couldn't get any info about it. All I found that `HTTP_HOST` is an ordinary Apache variable.

Answer (score 1):

As a followup, if you use Apache 2.4.19 or later, you can use a simpler format of Redirect within <Location> sections as detailed in the [mod_alias documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).  This new format uses [expression syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html), allowing the use of variables.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName lvh.me
    ServerAlias *.lvh.me

    <Location "/">
        Redirect "https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}"
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that only the Redirect directive works with this shorter format, RedirectPermanent etc. do not.