# Can I use Apache variables with mod_alias's `Redirect`, instead of using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

The Apache HTTP Server's `mod_alias` provides the `Redirect` directive which is great for simple redirects, like the following:

```
# Redirect login to https
Redirect permanent /login https://www.example.org/login
```

While many admins use `mod_rewrite` for redirects, the Apache documentation at [When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) suggest that in general, `mod_alias` is preferred over `mod_rewrite`. I'd like to use `mod_alias` more.

Can I use `Redirect` with [Apache variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars) such as `ServerName`? For example, to enforce that certain content is available over HTTPS only, I would want to do something like this:

```
Redirect permanent /login https://%{SERVER_NAME}/login
Redirect permanent /special-project-1 https://%{SERVER_NAME}/special-project-1
Redirect permanent /special-project-2 https://%{SERVER_NAME}/special-project-2
```

Neither of these work, and the literal string `%{SERVER_NAME}` is printed in the response:

```
host% curl http://www.example.org/login
...
302 Found
The document has moved <a href="https://%{SERVER_NAME}/login">here</a>.
```

Are Apache variables allowed with `mod_alias` directives? Are the variables available using a different syntax?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but ran across this thread looking w/ just this problem and found a solution.

With Apache 2.4 you can't do:

```
Redirect permanent /login https://%{SERVER_NAME}/login
```

But you can do:

```
<Location /login>
  Redirect permanent https://%{HTTP_HOST}/login
</Location>
```

Comment: You're answer is appreciated. This problem still bothers me, years later. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe a similar question is answered here:
https://serverfault.com/a/415796/337307

@shanemadden wrote:

> You cannot.  Redirect is able to handle simple redirections, where you're sending the client to a single, specific name, but does not have the ability to do complex substitutions (setting aside the fact that %{HTTP_HOST} is mod_rewrite-specific).
>
> Just stick with mod_rewrite.  mod_alias isn't capable of doing what you need.

Comment: That's similar, but is more about `mod_alias` verses `mod_rewrite`, and appears out of date. `%{HTTP_HOST}` is a `mod_rewrite` thing. Apache 2.2 didn't support many of these Apache variables back then.

Comment: Ah, perhaps this information from Apache's documentation is more helpful: `First, all Redirects are processed before Aliases are processed, and therefore a request that matches a Redirect or RedirectMatch will never have Aliases applied. Second, the Aliases and Redirects are processed in the order they appear in the configuration files, with the first match taking precedence.` I think this is saying you can't use Apache variables because the statement is evaluated in the wrong order. Please let me know if I'm misreading.

Comment: The referenced document is available here:https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: But Apache variables are a part of the core Apache code, and are not part of `mod_rewrite`. `mod_rewrite` has it's own set of parameters, like `%{HTTP_HOST}`, which I believe are different. In my case, I'm not using `mod_rewrite` at all, just `mod_alias` and the Apache core code.